# Flow sample SimpleSwitcher subcontainers

Tags: android, mortar, square-flow

In the recent update of Flow sample app, you introduced [SimpleSwitcher](https://github.com/square/flow/blob/master/flow-sample/src/main/java/com/example/flow/screenswitcher/SimpleSwitcher.java) which uses PathContext as a way of allowing customised sub-containers.

Could you elaborate on this term and/or give an example on what is meant by sub-containers?

Also how does it affect Mortar implementations? Since creating Mortar scopes require a parent Context, PathContext would create a chain of screen scopes: i.e. HomeScreen -> ListScreen -> DetailsScreen , each depending on its ancestor. So when I destroy HomeScreen scope, I lose the rest of the screen scopes and become very sad. I don't see the point of holding on to previous screen scopes after I leave them and would rather have the ActivityScope be the parent of each one (similar to previous Mortar example). Would this case require a different ScreenSwitcher impl or am I just missing something?

*Edit: ScreenSwitcher, not ScreenScoper*

Comment: We're working on it. A refactoring with better names and a smaller public api footprint should land soon. Stay tuned. In the meantime i have a branch on the mortar project that uses the new mortar sample stuff.

Comment: Neat, I'll have a look. Thanks!